# Float of each element in a matrix python ::

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying the convert the elements in a matrix to a float number, wanna the output to be 0.200, instead of 0.2 ?
(as the numerical precision is not the same as in Matlab for example, and it affects the results on what i want ?
When I tried float() I got the following error:
"TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Any help,
I attached the code:

```
import numpy as np

 A=np.array([[ 0.0186428,  -0.0056,         -0.0056,          0,          0,
            0],
             [-.1263,  0.42087542, -.1263,          0,          0,
             0],
             [-.1263, -.1263, 0.42087542,  0,          0,
             0],
            [0,         0,          0,          0.2,        -0,
             0        ],
            [ 0,          0,          0,         -0,          0.2,
              0        ],
            [-0,         -0,          0,          0,          0,
              0.2       ]])

            B=np.array([[1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0], 
            [0,0,0,0,0,1]])

           C=B*A*B  # float(C) NOT working ?
           print(C)
```

Comment: Your question focused on the diagonal `0.2` terms, and the non-essential difference in print format.  But the real error, or rather unexpected result, was in the off-diagonal terms, the `-00056` etc.  With this particular `B` (essentially `np.eye(6)`), element-wise multiplication (`B.*A.*B in MATLAB)  produces a (6,6) just like the matrix product, `B@A@B`, with the same diagonal values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `C` is already a numpy array with float valued numbers. You can check it yourself by printing

```
In [23]: C.dtype
Out[23]: dtype('float64')
```

If you want to change how the numpy arrays are printed to the console, you can edit the settings with [`np.set_printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html). For example:

```
In [21]: np.set_printoptions(precision=3, floatmode='fixed')

In [22]: C
Out[22]:
array([[ 0.019, -0.000, -0.000,  0.000,  0.000,  0.000],
       [-0.000,  0.421, -0.000,  0.000,  0.000,  0.000],
       [-0.000, -0.000,  0.421,  0.000,  0.000,  0.000],
       [ 0.000,  0.000,  0.000,  0.200,  0.000,  0.000],
       [ 0.000,  0.000,  0.000,  0.000,  0.200,  0.000],
       [ 0.000,  0.000,  0.000,  0.000,  0.000,  0.200]])
```

- The `precision` of 3 sets the values to be printed with three digits of precision
- The `floatmode` of `'fixed'` means:

> *Always print exactly precision fractional digits, even if this would
> print more or fewer digits than necessary to specify the value
> uniquely.*

### Note about multiplication

Based on your comment, it seems that what you are trying to achieve is *matrix multiplication* of matrices `A` and `B`. The * operator is element-wise multiplication. For [matrix multiplication](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html), you would want to use `np.matmul(np.matmul(B,A), B)`.

Comment: Thanks you for your feedback, 
Actually, I would like C[0,1]=  -0.1263   as the output in matlab,
Why can I get the same answer ?

Comment: The `*` operator is element-wise multiplication. What you want is matrix multiplication. Then, you would use `np.matmul(np.matmul(B,A), B)`.

Comment: you saved me , since yesterday trying all the things
please add it as answer so I could accept it

Comment: Glad that you found the problem! Edited the answer to include note about matrix multiplication

Answer (score 0):

`float` is built-in function and it is supposed to return single float, so you encountered error when you feed array of numbers, you should use [`.astype`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) method i.e.:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1,2,3])
arr2 = arr.astype(float)
print(arr2)
```

output

```
[1. 2. 3.]
```

(note `.`s after digits)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the other answer, use C.astype(float) for conversion.

If you you want to print with 3 decimal places use set_printoptions:

```
np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
print(C)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can round/set precision of your array with [np.around()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) and printing settings with [np.set_printoptions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html):

```
...

A = np.around(A, 3)
B = np.around(B, 3)

C=B*A*B
np.set_printoptions(precision=3, floatmode="fixed")
print(C)
```