# 9 decimal places of array elements in Python

Tags: python, numpy

How do I ensure that all the array elements after an operation are accurate to 9 decimal places? The desired output is attached.

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
A1=A*2
print([A1])
```

The desired output is

```
[array([[ 2.000000000,  4.000000000,  6.000000000],
       [ 8.000000000, 10.000000000, 12.000000000],
       [14.000000000, 16.000000000, 18.000000000]])]
```

Comment: If you tell Python to print a `float`, it will print the `float` using some standard formatting defined for the type - if you want to format the `float` as a specific string when printing, you should use a format string, for example `print(f'{2:.9f}')` - see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals). Note that, if the integer values you provided would *not* have been accurate so soon after the decimal, Python would have printed that anyway.

Comment: Have you tried [`np.set_printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Float of each element in a matrix python ::](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69709020/float-of-each-element-in-a-matrix-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.set_printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], dtype=float)
A1 = A * 2

np.set_printoptions(precision=9, floatmode='fixed')
print(A1)
```

You need to use `dtype` when creating the numpy array, since you're passing in a list of integers. Using `floatmode='fixed'` tells numpy to always print `precision` number of decimal places.